# Is "E-Mail der/s Antragstellerin/s:" a good/correct label for an email field?

Tags: gender-neutrality

Unfortunately I couldn't think of a neutral name unlike in other email fields of my online form like `E-Mail der Projektleitung`.
Also it is very important in my company to list both genders if no neutral word is possible. Unfortunately there's not enough space to spell out `E-Mail der Antragstellerin/ des Antragstellers`.

Is my suggestion in the question perfectly fine or would you do it differently? 
I'm unsure because I can't remember seeing this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If space matters we may omit the articles here. This would make the field entries considerably shorter:

> `E-Mail Projektleitung`
>   `E-Mail Antragsteller/in`

<sup>This answer deliberately does not discuss whether *Antragsteller* was gender neutral enough or not. It is up to the the company on how to treat such matters.</sup>

Comment: great, I didn't think about leaving out the articles because I was so used to seeing them! :D